# Does last_insert_id return the correct auto_increment id in a multiprocessing environment?

Tags: mysql, perl, multiprocessing

Here's some simplified code in my web application:

```
sub insert {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid > 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        &insert_to_mysql();
        my $last_id = &get_last_inserted(); # call mysql last_inserted_id
        exit(0);
    }
}

for my $i (1..10) {
    &insert();
}
```

Since `insert` is called in a multiprocessing environment, the order of `get_last_inserted` might be uncertain. Will it always return a correct last id corresponding to  `insert_to_mysql` subroutine? I read some documents saying that as long as the processes don't share the same mysql connection, the returned id will be always the right one. However, these processes are spawned from the same session, so I'm not sure if they share the mysql connection or not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> these processes are spawned from the same session

Are you saying you're forking and using the same connection in more than one process? That doesn't work at all, never mind `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. You can't have two processes reading and writing from the same connection! The response for one could end up in the other, assuming the two clients didn't clobber each other's request.

---

> Does last_insert_id return the correct auto_increment id in a multiprocessing environment?

According to MySQL's [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`,

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.

It would be useless otherwise. Since connections can't shared across processes, yes, it's safe.

Comment: Thanks, `connections can't shared across processes` solved all my concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MySql and perl, but in PHP that's quite the same issue, since it depends on the environment and not on the language. In PHP, last_insert_id expects one parameter: current connection! As long as multiple instances do not share the same connection ressource, passing the connection resource to the current mysql session should do the trick.

That's what I've found googling around: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/179/